# Error with jsonapi-serializers when trying to serialize grand children object

Tags: json, ruby, serialization

I have a main object 'mainobject'

inside MainObjectSerializer

`has_many: childObjects`

and inside ChildObjectSerializer:

`has_many: grandChildObjects`

but when i am trying to serialize:

`options = {include: ['childObjects','childObjects.grandChildObjects']}
 JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize(mainobject, options)`

I got errors:

`gems/jsonapi-serializers-0.14.0/lib/jsonapi-serializers/serializer.rb:163:in []: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`

Works well doing the serialization without the grandchild objects

Comment: All works fine now, problem was due to the sub object which didn't have ids

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the include used inside the options must follow the format defined by **format_name**

```
def format_name(attribute_name)
attribute_name.to_s.demodulize.camelize(:lower)
end
```

So for the serialisation to work, we change naming format to the following:

inside MainObjectSerializer

```
has_many: child_objects
```

and inside ChildObjectSerializer:

```
has_many: grand_child_objects
```

And the option should use *lower camel case* defined by **format_name**

```
options = {include: ['childObjects','childObjects.grandChildObjects']}
 JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize(mainobject, options)
```

So that we can obtain:

```
...
"included": [
{
"type": "childObject",
"id": "1234",
   "relationships": {
    "grandChildObjects": {
      "data": [         
      {
        "type": "grandChildObject",
        "id": "12"
      }
    ]
  }
 }
},
{
  "type": "grandChildObject",
  "id": "12",
...
```

Note that type is also using lower camel case and it is defined in the type method of the serializers:

```
def type
object.class.name.demodulize.camelize(:lower)
end
```